# Renaming index in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In neo4j I have created an index on the property name, but I want to rename the index.

Currently I access the node, delete the old index and set the new index name. Is there any method to do this without such a deletion?

Comment: Changed the question a little bit so the question begins with a complete problem statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is now way to rename an index using an "offical" way like REST or public Java API.

Theoretically it should be doable by doing some modifications inside your `graph.db` folder, however this would require a very intense knowledge of the internals of Neo4j. I strongly discourage going this approach.

The best way is to populate the new index and get rid of the old one.